# @Entity entity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Learning Spring MVC and Hibernate.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer {
```

In @Entity line there is an error : entity cannot be resolved to a type

I got jars from spring-framework-2.5.6 
Can you please tell me what I am missing here ?

Comment: import javax.persistence.Entity;

Comment: 2 suggestions: move up to the current version of Spring (3.1) and use an IDE which will help you with these issues, like Eclipse

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing an import statement:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

Comment: Thanks Sajan and Bozho, I appreciate.