# Entity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to do a simple app with Spring.
I installed the plugin spring (Spring Tool Suite (STS)) for eclipse.
I added Maven dependencies in the file pom.xml but did not load the jar files. I can not import the @Entity @Id in my class Produit and I do not know where is my problem.

im getting this error:

Entity cannot be resolved to a type.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sid</groupId>
    <artifactId>ebotique</artifactId>
    <name>EBotiqueV3</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Hibernate-->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL Connector-->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

im getting this error in the file pom.xml:

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753918/entity-entity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type this might be helpful

Comment: i checked this question. i tryed to import this ligne `import javax.persistence.Entity;` im getting this error : The import javax.persistence cannot be resolved

Comment: my problem is that maven didn't load the jar files.

Comment: @MarwenBta, please consider accepting the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Analysis

Please note that some of dependency definitions are out of the scope of the `dependencies` element (see `TODO:`):

```
<dependencies>
    …
</dependencies>

<!-- TODO: Out-of-the-scope dependency definitions! -->
<!-- Hibernate-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL Connector-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

…
```

## Solution

Just move the out-of-the-scope dependency definitions into the `dependencies` element.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to import `javax.persistence.Entity` and `javax.persistence.Id`. I believe their jar is also included in

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: my problem is that maven didn't load the jar files. and im getting this error in the file pom.xml:

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'.

Comment: i need help pls

Comment: Make sure your XML structure is valid. An open tag always need a close tag or slash(/) at the end.

Comment: i didn't do anything just I added Maven dependencies.

Comment: I don't see your entire pom.xml. But the dependency section should look like `<dependencies><dependency></dependency><dependency></dependency> ...</dependencies>`.

Comment: ty `<dependencies><dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL Connector-->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency></dependencies`

Comment: Your hibernate dependency is NOT inside of `<dependencies></dependencies>`.

Comment: ya ty i fixed my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just switched my code into the tag `<dependencies> … </dependencies>`

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL Connector-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Agree with you. This is it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep this block inside 
  org.hibernate hibernate-entitymanager 3.6.0.Final   org.hibernate hibernate-validator 4.1.0.Final    mysql mysql-connector-java 5.1.6

And also include hibernate-core dependency..

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above
Make sure your XML structure is valid. An open tag always need a close tag or slash(/) at the end.

In my case, the pom.xml file had a warning because I explicitly mentioned version of sql lite under . Thus, even after reload of project project was not getting updated(because of presence of warning).

To remove warning, I deleted the line that showed version number of sql lite dependency explicity and reloaded project. This fixed the issue for me.